# SQL Server connection string using Entity Framework in C# error

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I am currently using SQL Server to serve as my database, and this is my `app.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="HDIEntities" 
             connectionString="metadata=res://*/DbTablesDataModel.csdl|res://*/DbTablesDataModel.ssdl|res://*/DbTablesDataModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=desktopName\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=databaseName;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" 
             providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <entityFramework>
        <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
        <providers>
            <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
        </providers>
    </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

This is the call in my `InfoController` for the information inside the database:

```
public class InfoController : ApiController
{
     public HttpResponseMessage GetCountry(int id)
     {
         using (HDIEntities entities = new HDIEntities())
         {
             entities.Database.Connection.Open();
             var entity = entities.development_index.FirstOrDefault(hdi => hdi.HDI_ID == id);

             // Display an error message if the Id does not exist
             if (entity != null)
             {
                 return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, entity);
             }
             else 
             {
                 return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "Country with ID = " + id.ToString() + " not found");
             }
         }
     }
}
```

And this is my context class `DBContextModel`:

```
public partial class HDIEntities : DbContext
{
    public HDIEntities() : base("name=HDIEntities")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<development_index> development_index { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<suicide_statistics> suicide_statistics { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<unemployment_rates> unemployment_rates { get; set; }
}
```

This is the error I'm getting every time I try to go to the specific page using the connection.

[image: Page Error]

I have basically done everything regarding ports and testing connections. I've configured my SQL Server Configuration manager to make sure the TCP/IP is running, and I've tried every method mentioned in Microsoft documentation [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/configure-the-windows-firewall-to-allow-sql-server-access?view=sql-server-ver16). I've even tried deleting the .dll files included in the EF package and reinstalled them to see if that was the problem. I've hit a wall currently and would love some feedback or another pair of eyes to help me with this frustrating situation.

- Database: SQL Server 2019
- Languages: C# / Json / XML

Comment: It seems to me that the connection string is incorrect

Comment: @Roman I have left those out

Comment: Please post the error as text not image.

Comment: @DaleK This way is better since it's a bit much text. Image is clearer.

Comment: No, because on my phone I can't even read it. Errors should (as per the site guidelines) always be formatted text. And it is very unlikely we need to see more than the first couple of lines. The entire stack trace isn't necessary.

Comment: Your connection string indicates a server `desktopName\SQLEXPRESS`. If that is a remote machine have you checked that the server `desktopName` is actually pingable, and that SQL Browser Service is running, and that relevant firewall settings are open, and that `Allow Remote Connections` and TCP are actually enabled? On that machine do you have an instance of SQL Server named `SQLEXPRESS`?

Comment: @Charlieface Yes since I'm running on the same desktop and I have configured it to allow remote connections and tcp

Comment: I wonder why do you explicitly open the database connection inside of the controller?

Comment: If it's running on the same machine you actually don't need either of those, you need `Shared Memory`. But do you actually have an instance called `SQLEXPRESS` and is SQL Server service and SQL Browser service started?

Comment: @montonero to test the connection straight away, once I know it works then I can take it out.

Comment: @Charlieface yes the instance is in the connection string and the instance works because i tested it with a connection to the inbuilt database Explorer in Jetbrains Eider, and sql service and browser service are both enabled and running.

Comment: Check that `Shared Memory` is enabled, as well as `TCP`. Also try removing the whole EF connection from the project (including settings) and starting again

Comment: Add connection String Again With VS Vizard.

Comment: @Charlieface Shared Memory and TCP are both enabled